# Access to JSON Data Properties

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following string

```
{
    data: [
                {"Href":"1.jpg","Id":1,"Height":55,"Width":55,"Index":0},
                {"Href":"2.jpg","Id":2,"Height":55,"Width":55,"Index":1},
                {"Href":"3.jpg","Id":3,"Height":55,"Width":55,"Index":2},
                {"Href":"4.jpg","Id":4,"Height":55,"Width":55,"Index":3}
            ]
}
```

which is converted back to json

```
 var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(parsedString);
```

My question is:

How can I access each json attribute, for example `Something.Href` to extract `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` or only `Id` properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using "LINQ to JSON" instead of `DeserializeObject`, personally - although that may just due to having more experience with it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("Test.json");

        var json = JObject.Parse(text);
        var data = json["data"];
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["Href"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that, you can use `DeserializeObject` perfectly well, just accessing the members dynamically:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("Test.json");
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
        var data = json.data;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Href);
        }
    }
}
```